# how do I insert each row of a dataframe before the matching rows in a different dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have one small and one big dataframe

the small one

```
             WS      period shortCode identifier
6        197.78  2023-03-10   TC2-FFA       spot
7        196.79  2023-03-10   TC5-FFA       spot
8        253.13  2023-03-10   TC6-FFA       spot
9        198.13  2023-03-13  TC12-FFA       spot
10       166.67  2023-03-10  TC14-FFA       spot
11       217.86  2023-03-10  TC17-FFA       spot
18        97.00  2023-03-10   TD3-FFA       spot
19       172.19  2023-03-10   TD7-FFA       spot
20       205.71  2023-03-13   TD8-FFA       spot
21       175.63  2023-03-10  TD19-FFA       spot
22       115.45  2023-03-10  TD20-FFA       spot
23  11350000.00  2023-03-10  TD22-FFA       spot
24       232.14  2023-03-10  TD25-FFA       spot
```

the big one with MultiIndex

```
datumUnit                      $/mt       WS
identifier period shortCode                 
TC2BALMO   Mar 23 TC2-FFA    39.376  228.930
TC2CURMON  Mar 23 TC2-FFA    35.946  208.988
TC2+1_M    Apr 23 TC2-FFA    38.444  223.512
TC2+2_M    May 23 TC2-FFA    37.786  219.686
TC2+3_M    Jun 23 TC2-FFA    36.613  212.866
                            ...      ...
TD25+3Q    Q4 23  TD25-FFA   42.909  185.432
TD25+4Q    Q1 24  TD25-FFA   39.000      NaN
TD25+5Q    Q2 24  TD25-FFA   32.421      NaN
TD25+1CAL  Cal 24 TD25-FFA   34.250      NaN
TD25+2CAL  Cal 25 TD25-FFA   33.955      NaN
```

This is its MultiIndex

```
MultiIndex([( 'TC2BALMO', 'Mar 23',  'TC2-FFA'),
            ('TC2CURMON', 'Mar 23',  'TC2-FFA'),
            (  'TC2+1_M', 'Apr 23',  'TC2-FFA'),
                  ...
            (  'TD25+4Q',  'Q1 24', 'TD25-FFA'),
            (  'TD25+5Q',  'Q2 24', 'TD25-FFA'),
            ('TD25+1CAL', 'Cal 24', 'TD25-FFA'),
            ('TD25+2CAL', 'Cal 25', 'TD25-FFA')],
           names=['identifier', 'period', 'shortCode'], length=198)
```

I wish to insert the "spot" line of the small dataframe on top of the 2nd dataframe for each shortCode without changing the order of the big dataframe

intended result

```
datumUnit                      $/mt       WS
identifier period shortCode                 
spot     23-03-10 TC2-FFA      NaN   197.78        
TC2BALMO   Mar 23 TC2-FFA    39.376  228.930
TC2CURMON  Mar 23 TC2-FFA    35.946  208.988
TC2+1_M    Apr 23 TC2-FFA    38.444  223.512
TC2+2_M    May 23 TC2-FFA    37.786  219.686
TC2+3_M    Jun 23 TC2-FFA    36.613  212.866
                            ...      ...
spot     23-03-10 TD25-FFA      NaN   232.14  
TD25BALMO  Mar 23 TD25-FFA   48.902  211.331
TD25CURMON Mar 23 TD25-FFA   53.254  230.138
TD25+1_M   Apr 23 TD25-FFA   46.815  202.312
TD25+2_M   May 23 TD25-FFA   43.717  188.924
TD25+3_M   Jun 23 TD25-FFA   41.571  179.650
TD25+4_M   Jul 23 TD25-FFA   40.776  176.214
TD25+5_M   Aug 23 TD25-FFA   40.281  174.075
TD25CURQ   Q1 23  TD25-FFA   46.668  201.677
TD25+1Q    Q2 23  TD25-FFA   44.035  190.298
TD25+2Q    Q3 23  TD25-FFA   40.367  174.447
TD25+3Q    Q4 23  TD25-FFA   42.909  185.432
TD25+4Q    Q1 24  TD25-FFA   39.000      NaN
TD25+5Q    Q2 24  TD25-FFA   32.421      NaN
TD25+1CAL  Cal 24 TD25-FFA   34.250      NaN
TD25+2CAL  Cal 25 TD25-FFA   33.955      NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `.merge` to get the "row number" of each match.

```
new_rows = (
   df_spots
   .merge(
      df.reset_index() # remove MultiIndex
        .reset_index() # create "index" column with row numbers
      [["index", "shortCode"]],
      on="shortCode")
   .drop_duplicates(subset="shortCode")
   .set_index("index")
)
```

```
>>> new_rows
           WS      period shortCode identifier
index                                         
0      197.78  2023-03-10   TC2-FFA       spot
5      232.14  2023-03-10  TD25-FFA       spot
```

You can then `.concat`, `.sort_index` and restore the original MultiIndex.

```
(pd.concat(
   (new_rows, df.reset_index())) 
   .sort_index()
   .set_index(["identifier", "period", "shortCode"]))
```

```
                                      WS    $/mt
identifier period     shortCode                 
spot       2023-03-10 TC2-FFA    197.780     NaN
TC2BALMO   Mar 23     TC2-FFA    228.930  39.376
TC2CURMON  Mar 23     TC2-FFA    208.988  35.946
TC2+1_M    Apr 23     TC2-FFA    223.512  38.444
TC2+2_M    May 23     TC2-FFA    219.686  37.786
TC2+3_M    Jun 23     TC2-FFA    212.866  36.613
spot       2023-03-10 TD25-FFA   232.140     NaN
TD25+3Q    Q4 23      TD25-FFA   185.432  42.909
TD25+4Q    Q1 24      TD25-FFA       NaN  39.000
TD25+5Q    Q2 24      TD25-FFA       NaN  32.421
TD25+1CAL  Cal 24     TD25-FFA       NaN  34.250
TD25+2CAL  Cal 25     TD25-FFA       NaN  33.955
```

Comment: Thanks. sorry I have "AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values", also I need to keep the date as it is "23-03-10" instead of "Mar 23"

Comment: You need to use `pd.to_datetime` to turn it into a datetime. I've edited the answer.

Comment: thanks, still fails at the first part of the code, now the error becomes "KeyError: "['index'] not in index"

Comment: Is there a MultiIndex on the "big" dataframe?

Comment: yes, shall I reset_index all of its indexes?

Comment: I guess you'd need another `reset_index` for this approach to work then e.g. `.merge(df.reset_index().reset_index()`

Comment: Thanks, your code works! however I would love to have kept the "shortcode" values of the inserted rows... yours have NaN for those values

Comment: I forgot to include it when re-ordering `new_rows` columns after the `.drop`/`.rename` - should be fixed now.